# defined(XXXX) macro in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, operators, defined

I'm going through the BSON source code, and came across something I've never seen before.

[Line 22 in bson-macros.h](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver/blob/master/src/libbson/src/bson/bson-macros.h#L22):

```
#if !defined(BSON_INSIDE) && !defined(BSON_COMPILATION)
#error "Only <bson.h> can be included directly."
#endif
```

What is the `defined(XXXX)` macro above? I can guess what it does, but I can't seem to find any documentation about it. Is it specific to some compilers? It gives me a W4 warning on Microsoft Visual C++ (that I'm trying to resolve in my project).

Comment: [This preprocessor reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor) might be helpful.

Comment: Works like `#ifdef` but allows you to make a multi-predicate condition instead of multiple nested `#ifdef` blocks.

Comment: Did you google "defined c"?

Comment: @MillieSmith Nope, I put the word 'macro' in! There it is, on the second page when I remove that word ><

Comment: Hm. It's the first non-featured result for me :S. That's strange.

Comment: Google is weird and non-opaque nowadays :/

Comment: For anyone who is interested I've submitted a possible bug to the MongoDB user forum to raise the root issue here. I'll post a link here once it's approved.

Comment: Google is working just fine. A search for "c defined" gave this as first hit: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Defined.html.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [6.10.1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.1p1)

> The expression that controls conditional inclusion shall be an integer
>   constant expression except that: identifiers (including those
>   lexically identical to keywords) are interpreted as described
>   below;166) and it may contain unary operator expressions of the form
>
> ```
>   defined identifier
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>   defined ( identifier )
> ```
>
> *which evaluate to 1 if the identifier is currently defined as a macro
>   name* (that is, if it is predefined or if it has been the subject of a
>   `#define` preprocessing directive without an intervening `#undef` directive with the same subject identifier), 0 if it is not.

It is not `macro` - it is an operator.

Comment: Wow. Thank you - I had no idea this existed.

Comment: That's a C reference. Is it also valid for C++?

Comment: @aaronsnoswell.: Again we see how tagging leads to these kind of situation. My answer was solely given for C - I am not aware whether the C++11 or C++14 standard alllows it  or not...if I find anything useful(absence or presene ) will update.